# Fabric.js - Touch Event Propagation

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, fabricjs

I have an HTML5 page, and it looks like this:

```
<html>
<head></head>

<body>
<canvas id="c1" width="500" height="500" />

</body>
</html>
```

I used Bootstrap 3 and Fabric.js as a canvas library. When I run it on mobile device, I have got an issue that when I touch the object on canvas and move it, the page is moved too. Seems the touch event is also handled by mobile device browser.

What I expect is that to stop the default event handle for mobile device browser, so when I touch the object in canvas and move it, the web page will not move as well. How can I make this with Fabric.js?

Answer (score 1):

I have changed the way while I making the html:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=0.5, user-scalable=no">
```

And then, to prevent browser default zoom bouncing, we can bind "touchmove" in document and disable it. That's from jQuery mobile, but vmousemove = touchmove for mobile device somehow.

```
$(document).on("vmousemove", "body", function(e) {
                    e.stopPropagation();
                    e.preventDefault();
                    return false;
                });
```

This is not about Fabric.js anyway, so I don't have to change Fabric.js or else.